# Event on in dojox/dgauges/TextIndicator

Tags: javascript, dojo

I create this gauge using dojo, but now I need to add events to some element, in this case to the textindicator.

I have been reading the documentation http://bill.dojotoolkit.org/api/1.9/dojox/dgauges/TextIndicator

and dojox/dgauges/TextIndicator doesnt have methods 'on' or 'connect', but dojox/gauges/TextIndicator (what will be deprecated) has both.

Is there a way to add an event to my dojox/dgauges/textindicator, or may replace it to other element?

Here my code
http://fiddle.jshell.net/THJqV/11/

For example, I need to add an onclick event to: `var indicatorText = new TextIndicator();`

Answer (score 1):

New `TextIndicator` is realy somewhat lame but I can provide little hack.

```
// track clicks on title TextIndicator
var titleText = 'Reporte Comparativa Comercial-Adquisicion';
gauge.on('click', function(event) {
    var target = event.target;
    if(target.childNodes && target.childNodes[0].data == titleText)
        alert("Bingo!");
});
```

First of all you can add `.on()` to your gauge. But then you'll need some hack to distinguish clicks. See http://fiddle.jshell.net/BRv4s/

Comment: thanks!, I finally found a similar way and I answered too. I have no idea which one is better

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution has been posted on the Dojo forum: http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/Event-on-exists-in-TextIndicator-Gauges-but-no-in-Dgauges-tt4000219.html#a4000221

Comment: yeah, I made that question there :)

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution before the 2 great answers posted and I'm going to post it too.

I only add this lines and works!:

```
gauge.refreshRendering();
gauge.getElementRenderer("legend" + id).on('click', function () { alert('goku')});
```

Here the example http://jsfiddle.net/MacroX/THJqV/12/

Comment: That's good for legends but not for just any `TextIndicator`. But if it's good for your needs then use it. It looks alittle simplier then mine. The only thing I'd change is I'd move `gauge.getElementRenderer("legend" + id).on('click', function () { alert('goku')});` from `addGauge()`. This way it will be esear to add different handlers for different legends.